# TCP/IP request in Tosca

Tags: testing, tcp, automation, tosca

We have a requirement to validate TCP/IP Sample request in Tosca; is the Tosca support TCP kind of request ?

I tried to call the TCP request but not sure how we can do that in Tosca; will the neoload support in tosca or is there any other way we have?

Comment: What kind of TCP/IP Sample request is it? Do you mean a HTTP request?

Comment: It is kind of server address and port number , looking same like Jmeter tcp sample request . We have server address and port number & will send a json request to server